# How do I compile KanColleTool?

Tags: compiling, git, cmake

I have downloaded the [KanColleTool](https://github.com/KanColleTool/KanColleTool/) repository from GitHub with this command:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/KanColleTool/KanColleTool.git KanColleTool.git
```

However when I run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
```

...this happens:

```
CMake Error at viewer/src/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt5WebKitWidgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"Qt5WebKitWidgets", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5WebKitWidgets"
with any of the following names:

Qt5WebKitWidgetsConfig.cmake
qt5webkitwidgets-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5WebKitWidgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "Qt5WebKitWidgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "Qt5WebKitWidgets" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/zmaj/KanColleTool.git/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the development libraries using

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

to get

```
Qt5WebKitWidgetsConfig.cmake
qt5webkitwidgets-config.cmake
```

and start `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` again

*Sample output*

```
~/tmp/KanColleTool.git] master ± cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr                                                 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/aboettger/tmp/KanColleTool.git
```

Comment: "Wow! I wouldn't have thought of that! I learned something today! Upvoted!"